# Why do I get a "String index out of range" error when I run this program?

Tags: java

I am creating a program that converts roman numeral input to it's integer value and every time I run the program I get an error that says,

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
    at romannumeralconverter.RomanNumeralConverter.convert(RomanNumeralConverter.java:20)
    at romannumeralconverter.RomanNumeralConverter.romanInput(RomanNumeralConverter.java:68)
    at romannumeralconverter.RomanNumeralConverter.printValue(RomanNumeralConverter.java:72)
    at romannumeralconverter.RomanNumeralConverter.main(RomanNumeralConverter.java:77)
Java Result: 1"
```

Now I am new to programming so I don't know what this means exactly. I am guessing my conversion algorithm is wrong in which the roman numeral entered is not read by the loop. Here is what I have:

```
public class RomanNumeralConverter {  

public String getUserInput() {

    Scanner numberInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a roman numeral in uppercase: ");
    String userInput = numberInput.next();
    numberInput.close();
    return userInput;
}

public int convert (String userInput) {
    int result = 0;
    int subtractamount = 0;
    int x = userInput.length();
    while(x != 0) {
    char romanConvert = userInput.charAt(x);
        if(x >= 1) {
        if(convertChar(romanConvert) >= convertChar(userInput.charAt(x - 1))) {
        subtractamount += convertChar(userInput.charAt(x - 1));
    }
}
    result += convertChar(romanConvert);
    x--;

}
result -= subtractamount;
return result;

}

public static char convertChar(char value) {
char result;
switch (value) {
    case 'I':
        result = 1;
        break;
    case 'V':
        result = 5;
        break;
    case 'X':
        result = 10;
        break;
    case 'L':
        result = 50;
        break;
    case 'C':
        result = 100;
        break;
    case 'D':
        result = 500;
        break;
    case 'M':
        result = 1000;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid character!");
        result = 0;
        break;
               }
return result;
}

public int romanInput() {       
    return convert(getUserInput());
}

public void printValue() {
System.out.println(romanInput());
}

public static void main (String[] args) {

new RomanNumeralConverter().printValue();
}
}
```

If my algorithm is wrong, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: We appreciate that you posted the stack trace.  It is also helpful, when you do so, to indicate what line you're referring to.  The stack trace says the error is occurring on line 20 of `RomanNumeralConverter.java`.  However, the 20th line of your code is probably not the one causing the error.  It may be that some irrelevant lines got removed when you posted.  It's best to look at your editor or IDE to see which line is line 20, then put a comment or some other indication on it to let us know what the actual line is.  Thank you.

Comment: @ajb Looked at line 20, and it is 'char romanConvert = userInput.charAt(x);' but I was told below to change it to 'userInput.charAt(x-1);'. I did that and now all my conversions come out as 0.

Comment: Just in case it wasn't obvious, "String index out of range" means that you indexed a string and the index value you used was not between zero and the length of the string minus one.  And the stack trace tells you precisely which line experienced this problem.  You should have figured this problem out yourself, and you probably would have if you had made the effort to understand the messages rather than treating them as mystical incantations.

Comment: @HotLicks for an online class with only two months of programming experience and just a book to guide me, forgive me if I can't catch the little mistakes even if I am referenced to the line it is at.

Comment: The point is, actually READ the error messages.  Don't think you have to memorize every one or consult a Ouija board -- the words in the message have meaning.  There's nothing about this problem that should be beyond the comprehension of someone with a week of experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `userInput.charAt(x);` to `userInput.charAt(x - 1);`

```
charAt starts with index 0 to length -1
```

or `int x = userInput.length() - 1;`

@nd issue, everything coming out as 0

You are actually using **uppercase characters in switch statement**.

so just add below statement,in the starting of your function `convert(String userInput)`

```
 userInput = userInput.toUpperCase(); // converts user input to uppercase , even if its is already or not.
```

code

```
public int convert(String userInput) {
        userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
        int result = 0;
        int subtractamount = 0;
        int x = userInput.length() - 1;
        while (x != 0) {
            char romanConvert = userInput.charAt(x);
            if (x >= 1) {
                if (convertChar(romanConvert) >= convertChar(userInput.charAt(x - 1))) {
                    subtractamount += convertChar(userInput.charAt(x - 1));
                }
            }
            result += convertChar(romanConvert);
            x--;

        }
        result -= subtractamount;
        return result;

    }
```

**output**

```
Enter a roman numeral in uppercase: adig
Invalid character!
Invalid character!
Invalid character!
Invalid character!
501
```

Comment: I just did what you suggested but I still get that issue. I am putting that in the first line at the start of my convert method, and I am entering them in uppercase as well but I get 0.

Comment: @NEPat10 output added for your reference. Are you able to do it..??

Comment: I am obviously doing something wrong. Would it be too much to ask for you to edit it over with exactly what you have down in that method?

Comment: @NEPat10 ok posted the method. :)

Comment: Thank you. I am not just getting 0 anymore, but there are some bugs I need to work out. I keep getting 1 when I input VI and I get 6 when input XVI.

Comment: @NEPat10 yes that is your algo you can fix, but pls accept the answer and upvote

Answer (score 1):

You should start with

```
int x = userInput.length() - 1;
```

The last character in a string is at the index - (length-of-string - 1), not length-of-string.

Comment: Alright, I don't get that error now, but everything comes out as 0.

Comment: @NEPat10 answer posted for your both issues, exception and everything coming out as 0. Have a look